# it is possible to make bode plot with jsxgraph

Tags: plot, jsxgraph

I am desperately looking for how to put a graph under jsxgraph to draw a graph with x axis which evolves in logarithmic. like this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bode_plot

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for how to plot with a logarithmic vertical axis. It is adapted from an example by Murray Bourne, see https://www.intmath.com/cg3/jsxgraph-coding-summary.php. The code looks like this:

```
const board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('jxgbox', { 
    boundingbox: [-5, 6, 5, -4], axis:false
});

// Vertical axis with logarithmic scale
var attr = JXG.Options.board.defaultAxes.x;
attr.ticks.drawZero = false;
var xAxis = board.create('axis', [[0, 0], [1, 0]], attr);

attr = JXG.Options.axis;
var yAxis = board.create('line', [[0, 0], [0, 1]], attr);

attr = JXG.Options.board.defaultAxes.y.ticks;
attr.drawLabels = true;
attr.drawZero = false;
attr.generateLabelText = function (tick, zero) {
    return (Math.pow(10, Math.round(tick.usrCoords[2] - zero.usrCoords[2]))).toString();
}

var ticksY = board.create('ticks', [yAxis, 1], attr);   

// Plot two functions
var post = (x) => JXG.Math.log10(x); 
var f1 = (x) => x*x;
var f2 = (x) => Math.exp(x);

board.create('functiongraph', [(x) => post(f1(x))], {
  name: 'x^2',
  withLabel: true
});

board.create('functiongraph', [(x) => post(f2(x))], {
  name: 'e^x',
  withLabel: true,
  strokeColor: 'red'
});
```

See it live at https://jsfiddle.net/4nbajsch/5/.