# Changing the mouse over shown coordinates of points

Tags: jsxgraph

I want to change the coordinates that are shown when you highlight a point. Reason for this is that the point is on a graph with logarithmic axis. According to the question [it is possible to make bode plot with jsxgraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63670056/it-is-possible-to-make-bode-plot-with-jsxgraph/63689274#63689274) I use the generateLabelText attribute to get a logarithmic tick label. But I need this for the coordinates of points as well - otherwise students might get very confused.

E.g. if the point is at (-1, 2) the mouse over text should be (0.1, 2) for a logarithmic x-axis.

Is there a way to achive this? I craded an issue on Github https://github.com/jsxgraph/jsxgraph/issues before I found the JSXgraph section on stack overflow. I hope no one will be offended.

Edit: An answer was provided here by Alfred Wassermann: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71869116/14406173